# CSS Isolation in Blazor + Bootstrap + SCSS: can it work? (::deep selector)

Tags: css, blazor

Bootstrap is now offered (also) in SASS format, very useful, modifying base variables, creating one only resulting CSS file, for use in a web site (base bootstrap + custom, only one minimized file).

Now, the latest release of Blazor offers CSS isolation, that looks very promising and flexible.

But, being able to use a modified (SCSS) Bootstrap style appears impossible: we should add (manually?) the '::deep' pseudo to each style, given that we will have a lot of different pages and components.

Did anyone think to this, or have any idea?

Comment: There is no `::deep` pseudo element in CSS.

Comment: After two years? :-) Thank you! But a few months ago I saw this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68913197/suppress-blazor-css-deep-warning

Comment: Shadow DOM offers style isolation. No need for another unwelcome proprietary Microsoft addition.

Comment: True, but of course this is just an opinion... :-) Thanks again!