# Suppress Blazor css ::deep warning

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

In a css file of an asp.net Blazor app when I use `::deep` VS emits a warning "Validation (CSS 4.0): "::deep" is not a valid pseudo-element." That might be true for regular CSS, but not in the context of a Blazor app.

Is there a way to suppress it? `Right-click -> Suppress -> In File / In Source` do nothing.

Comment: https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/dotnet/aspnetcore/32500/836536994

Comment: Some information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204217/how-to-suppress-specific-css-2-0-validation-errors-in-visual-studio-2008

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add `deep` to the vendor specific extensions.
I've added it to the Microsoft extension and it works.

Open with an editor (in Administrator mode) the file:
**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\<your version>\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Languages\Schemas\CSS\1033\css-vendor-ms.xml**

Go to line ~69 and add the following code:

```xml
    <CssPseudo name="::deep"
             _locID="ms-browse-pseudo-element"
             _locAttrData="description"
             version="3.0"
             browsers="IE11"
             description="Blazor child component support."
             standard-reference="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0"/>
```

Restart Visual Studio.

Now I can see the source code as:
[image: Deep pseudo element]

Comment: how does people end knowing this stuff? It was annoying me more than I like to admit. Thanks! worked perfectly. here sir is your cookie.

Comment: Is this possible to do within a solution? So that anyone that uses it gets rid of the issue.

Comment: For Visual Studio 2022, the file is now at:  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\<your version>\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Languages\Schemas\CSS\1033\css-vendor-ms.xml

Comment: The CSSPseudo hack does not work for VS 2022, but the application still builds and runs with no problems.  It is just annoying.  Is there a specific error code that can be suppressed in the .csproj file?

Answer (score 5):

For Resharper users, editing the css-vendor-ms.xml is needed but does not completely solve the issue.  Resharper will continue to highlight ::deep elements as errors in your solution.  This is [currently a known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-62195), which will hopefully be resolved in a future build.

As a work around, go to Resharper Options --> Code Inspection --> Inspection Severity --> CSS -->  Potential Code Quality Issues --> Unknown CSS symbol and drop the severity to Warning (or lower).

Comment: The bug has been unfixed for 3 years: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-481832/Support-deep-combinator-for-Blazor-CSS-isolation

Answer (score 3):

This has now been fixed as of the latest preview version of Visual Studio 2022:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Support-::deep-in-razorcss-CSS-isolati/1623976

I just downloaded 17.3 and my project is now down to zero warnings again! Look forward to it being released properly.

Comment: Yes, it works now for css files and it is released. But I still get a warning in scss files, although the ::deep is forwarded to the .css file and so it works: "::deep is only allowed in file names ending with .razor.css".